# The right time to use .count() in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-orm, django-1.9

These are the models i have in my small project

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    location = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)
```

A list of tags are given to me (a maximum of 3). I need to find the number of times tag each of these tags appear on Post. lets say ["funny","geek","tech"]

For getting tag count i am doing

```
    for tag in tags:
        tag_data[tag] = Post.objects.filter(
            tags__name=tag,
            location__distance_lte=(
                pnt, D(km=distance))).count()
```

Then i fetch all post data using the following query.

```
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
             tags__name__in=tags,
             location__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=distance)))
```

I am already looping on posts at the end of function.

```
for post in posts:
   #some logic
```

So i know i have the tags data there. No need to do seperate data queries like above to find count. But i figured out that if i want to find count of tags inside the for loop i need 1 more for loop inside that for loop.

```
for post in posts:
   #some logic
   for tag in post.tags:
      #some logic
```

So my question which one is more efficient in here. Fetching using .count() as i did or nested for loops.

Comment: What is `em_id` in `tag_data[em_id]`?

Comment: That was a typo. Updated

Comment: As I understand it, you want to count the number of `Tag` that have been tagged in a specific `Post`. Correct? Or you want to count how many `Post` a `Tag` have been used in? What's the actual thing you want to count?

Comment: I wan to know in how many posts a tag has been appeared.

Comment: Don't mind the location field, i am restricting the count to a particular area

Comment: Your second approach would be very slow because each call to `tag.name` in the inner loop will fire a new query. For your first approach there will be one query for each tag. You should use one aggregation query(as suggested by @MarcusLind) and one for getting all posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Django ORM there's something called **Aggregation** that is using the `.annotate()` and `.aggregate()` methods to add the functionality you're looking for to the queries. ([Docs on Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/)).

There are plenty of examples of how you can do things such as getting a `Count`, `Avg`, `Sum` and more.This can also be done throughout Many-To-Many relationships just like in the case of yours.

[There's even an example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) in the documentation that is very similar to your case.

> For example, if you are retrieving a list of books, you may want to know how many authors contributed to each book. Each Book has a many-to-many relationship with the Author; we want to summarize this relationship for each book in the QuerySet.

To count the amount of `Post` a `Tag` has appeared in you would just do this:

```
# Add any arguments you want to the filter() to narrow down the Tag query set.
tags = Tags.objects.filter().annotate(Count('post_set'))
# You access it as post_set__count
```

EDIT:

Based on the comments that you supplied, you want to add conditions to the annotation and the query, to be able to only count posts that are within a radius. To do this you use what Django calls [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions).

With the help of Conditional Expressions you can add conditions to your `.annotate()`.

Example:

```
tags = Tags.objects.filter().annotate(Count(
        Case(When(post_set__location="1", then=1), output_field=IntegerField())
))
```

Please read the Documentation to find the proper way to use it in your case. You can see the [Conditional Expressions  with Aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation).

Comment: I understood. But i am confused where to apply filter on Posts. As you see i need only the posts who satisfy the location condition(*location__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=distance))*).

Comment: You previously wrote that we should ignore the location field... But if I understand you correctly, you want to count the number of `Post` that a `Tag` exists in, but only count `Post` that are inside a radius? So you don't want the total `Tag` count, you want to limit it by `Post` location?

Comment: Yes. And sorry for misdirecting. When i said Ignore i meant just consider it as filter field. I want Tag count and limit it by Post location